Density distribution of a random variable
Please tell me where in the solution I made a mistake and what it was? I have an answer to the problem, but it is different. Problem condition: The random vector is distributed in area D (0<x<2,3<y<5). Find the distribution density of the random variable XY.
$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{3}^{5}Adxdy=4A=1\rightarrow A=\frac{1}{4}$
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}$
$f_{A(x,y)}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(z-A(x,y))f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$
$f_{xy}(z)=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{3}^{5}\delta(z-xy)\frac{1}{4}dxdy=|t=xy,dt=\frac{dx}{y},3\rightarrow3y,5\rightarrow5y|=$
$=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{3y}^{5y}\delta(z-t)\frac{y}{4}dtdy=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}h(5y-z)h(z-3y)ydy=$
$=\frac{1}{4}\int_{max(z,0)}^{max(z,2)}ydy=\frac{1}{8}y^{2}|_{max(z,0)}^{max(z,2)}=\frac{1}{8}((max(z,2))^{2}-(max(z,0))^{2})=$
$=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{1}{4},z\leqslant0\\
\frac{1}{8}(4-z^{2}),0\leqslant z\leqslant2\\
0,2\leqslant z
\end{array}
\right.$
$h(k)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1, k>0\\
0, k\leqslant0
\end{array}
\right.$
$h(k)$ - Heaviside function
$\delta(k)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\infty, k=0\\
0, k\neq0
\end{array}
\right.$
$\delta(k)$ - Dirac delta function

$dt=y,dx$ and not $dt=dx/y$ ?

You have $dt=y\,dx$ and not $dt=y/dx$, but you may have a problem for $y=0$, so I use $dt=x\,dy$ instead, which gives
\begin{align*}
f_{xy}(z) &= \frac{1}{4}\,\int_0^2 \int_3^5 \delta(z-xy) dx \, dy \quad | \, t=xy, x=x \\
\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\,\int_3^{5} \int_{0}^{2x} \delta(z-t) \frac{1}{x} dt \, dx \quad | \, s=z-t\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\,\int_3^5 \frac{1}{x}\left(\int_{z-2x}^{z} \delta(s) \, ds \right) dx\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\,\int_3^5 \frac{H(z)-H(z-2x)}{x} dx\quad | \, u=z-2x\\
\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left(H(z)\ln\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)-\int_{z-10}^{z-6} \frac{H(u)}{z-u}\, du\right)\\
\\
&= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        \dfrac{1}{4}\,\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)H(z) & \mbox{if } z \leqslant 6 \\
        \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)-\displaystyle\int_{0}^{z-6} \dfrac{1}{z-u}\, du\right) & \mbox{if } 6 \leqslant z < 10 \\
        \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right)-\displaystyle\int_{z-10}^{z-6} \dfrac{1}{z-u}\, du\right) & \mbox{if } z > 10
    \end{array}
\right.\\
\\
&= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        0& \mbox{if } z \leqslant 0 \\
        \dfrac{1}{4}\,\ln\left(\dfrac{5}{3}\right) & \mbox{if } 0 < z \leqslant 6 \\
        \dfrac{1}{4} \, \ln\left(\dfrac{10}{z}\right) & \mbox{if } 6 < z \leqslant 10 \\
        0 & \mbox{if } z > 10
    \end{array}
\right.
.
\end{align*}

Kermatoni, thank you very much for the detailed answer! If you have the opportunity, look at my similar question at the link. I want to understand whether I have mastered the principle of working with Dirac and Heaviside functions. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963702/find-the-distribution-density-of-the-sum-of-two-independent-random-variables-ea

It's too long and not really well written.

Kermatoni, I do not quite understand what you mean. As I understand it, you said that I did not solve it in the fastest way, that is, some actions could have been skipped. Perhaps this is true. It is important for me to understand whether I worked with the Dirac and Heaviside functions correctly?

I checked for the main property of density and everything came together, but this could have happened because I made several mistakes when applying these functions and they mutually excluded each other. That is, I want to get an answer from you to the question: Did I correctly use the Dirac and Heaviside functions in my solution?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963702/find-the-distribution-density-of-the-sum-of-two-independent-random-variables-ea
