Find the distribution density of the sum of two independent random variables, each of which has a distribution f(x)
I am learning to work with the Dirac and Heaviside delta function. Please tell me if I did the task correctly? A random variable has a probability distribution density $f(x)=Ax$, $1<x<3$. Find the distribution density of the sum of two independent random variables, each of which has a distribution $f(x)$.
$f_{A(x,y)}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(z-A(x,y))f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\rho(x)\rho(y)dxdy=\int_{1}^{3}\int_{1}^{3}A^{2}xydxdy=$
$=A^{2}\frac{1}{2}x^{2}|_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}y^{2}|_{1}^{3}=A^{2}\frac{1}{4}8^{2}=16A^{2} =1\rightarrow A=\frac{1}{4}$
$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{1}^{3}\int_{1}^{3}\delta(z-(x+y))\frac{1}{16}xydxdy=$
$=|t=x+y,dt=dy,x=t-y,1\rightarrow1+y,3\rightarrow3+y|=$
$=\frac{1}{16}\int_{1}^{3}\int_{y+1}^{y+3}\delta(z-t)(t-y)ydtdy=$
$=|u=z-t,du=-dt,t=z-u,1+y\rightarrow z-(1+y),3+y\rightarrow z-(3+y)|=$
$=-\frac{1}{16}\int_{1}^{3}\int_{z-(1+y)}^{z-(3+y)}\delta(u)(z-u-y)ydudy=$
$=-\frac{1}{16}\int_{1}^{3}((H(z-(3+y))-H(z-(1+y)))(z-y)y-\int_{z-(1+y)}^{z-(3+y)}\delta(u)uydu)dy=$
$\int_{z-(1+y)}^{z-(3+y)}\delta(u)uydudy=0, \text{ because } \int_{a}^{b}\delta(k-0)f(k)dk=f(0),0\in[a,b]$
$=-\frac{1}{16}\int_{1}^{3}((H(z-(3+y))-H(z-(1+y)))(z-y)ydudy=$
$=-\frac{1}{16}(\int_{1}^{3}H(z-(3+y))(z-y)ydudy-\int_{1}^{3}H(z-(1+y))(z-y)ydudy)=$
$=|k1=z-(3+y),dk1=-dy,y=z-(3+k1),1\rightarrow z-4,3\rightarrow z-6;k2=z-(1+y),dk2=-dy,y=z-(1+k2),1\rightarrow z-2,3\rightarrow z-4|=$
$=-\frac{1}{16}(\int_{z-4}^{z-6}H(k1)(z-(z-(3+k1)))(z-(3+k1))dk1dy-\int_{z-2}^{z-4}H(k2)(z-(z-(1+k2)))(z-(1+k2))dk2dy)=$
$=-\frac{1}{16}(I1-I2)=I$
$I1=\int_{z-4}^{z-6}H(k1)(z-(z-(3+k1)))(z-(3+k1))dk1dy=$
$=\int_{z-4}^{z-6}H(k1)(3+k1)(z-(3+k1))dk1dy=$
$=\int_{z-4}^{z-6}H(k1)((3+k1)z-(3+k1)^{2})dk1dy=$
$\begin{cases}
0,z<4\\
\int_{z-4}^{0}((3+k1)z-(3+k1)^{2})dk1dy=...=-\frac{z^{3}}{6}+5z-\frac{28}{3},4\leqslant z<6\\
\int_{z-4}^{z-6}((3+k1)z-(3+k1)^{2})dk1dy=-4z+\frac{26}{3},6\leqslant z
\end{cases}$
$I2=\int_{z-2}^{z-4}H(k2)(z-(z-(1+k2)))(z-(1+k2))dk2dy=$
$=\int_{z-2}^{z-4}H(k2)((1+k2)z-(1+k2)^{2})dk2dy=$
$\begin{cases}
0,z<2\\
\int_{z-4}^{0}((1+k2)z-(1+k2)^{2})dk2dy=...=-\frac{z^{3}}{6}+z-\frac{2}{3},2\leqslant z<4\\
\int_{z-4}^{z-6}((1+k2)z-(1+k2)^{2})dk2dy=-4z+\frac{26}{3},4\leqslant z
\end{cases}$
$I=\begin{cases}
0,z<2\\
\frac{1}{16}(\frac{z^{3}}{6}-z+\frac{2}{3}),2\leqslant z<4\\
\frac{1}{16}(\frac{-z^{3}}{6}+9z-18),4\leqslant z<6\\
0,6\leqslant z
\end{cases}$
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X+Y}(z)dz=\int_{2}^{4}\frac{1}{16}(\frac{z^{3}}{6}-z+\frac{2}{3})dz+\int_{4}^{6}\frac{1}{16}(\frac{-z^{3}}{6}+9z-18)dz=1$ - then the resulting function satisfies the density property.
The resulting function satisfies the density property, but errors can exclude each other, so I ask you to look at my solution.
numerical calculations in a mathematical package

I haven't checked your developments, because it shouldn't be so laborious. You started correctly by noting that the PDF of a random variable $Z = \phi(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
f_Z(z) = \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}x \int_\Bbb{R}\mathrm{d}y \; \delta(z-\phi(x,y))f_{X,Y}(x,y).
$$
Now, two simplications can be made. Firstly, since $X$ and $Y$ are iid, we have $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = f(x)f(y)$, with $f(t) = At \cdot 1_{[1,3]}(t)$. Secondly, given that $\phi(x,y) = x+y$ in the present case, one integral can be eliminated straightforwardly due to the Dirac delta, which enforces the equality $z = \phi(x,y) = x+y$ in the remaining integral. In consequence, we end up with
$$
f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_\Bbb{R} f(x)f(z-x) \,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
We have rederived a well-known result, namely that the PDF of the sum of two random variables is given by the convolution product of their respective PDFs, i.e. $f_{X+Y} = f_X * f_Y$. In the present case, one has thus :
$$
f_{X+Y}(t) = A^2 \int_\Bbb{R} x1_{[1,3]}(x) \cdot (t-x)1_{[1,3]}(t-x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \left.A^2x^2\left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{x}{3}\right)\right|_{x=\max(1,t-3)}^{x=\min(t-1,3)},
$$
where we used the relation $1_{[a,b]}(t-x) = 1_{[t-b,t-a]}(x)$ and $1_{[\alpha,\beta]} \cdot 1_{[a,b]} = 1_{[\max(\alpha,a),\min(\beta,b)]}$.
